# Xamarin - android blank app stops on launching, no errors or warnings

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I cant launch any app in xamarin on android, app just stops. There are 0 errors or warnings in IDE, i just get the communicate "xxx has stopped". It is just newly created blank app with nothing changed. I'm working on the newest vs 2017 and updated xamarin. Tried both launhcing app in API 25 (7.1) and 23 (6.0) emulators. Meanwile, UWP works fine. Do you have any ideas what causes this and how to fix it?

Edit:

A bit of logs and messages:

```
10-14 16:47:00.571 I/MonoDroid( 3336): System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Inżynierka.Droid.MainActivity' from assembly 'Inżynierka.Droid, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
10-14 16:47:00.571 I/MonoDroid( 3336):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Type:internal_from_name (string,bool,bool)
10-14 16:47:00.571 I/MonoDroid( 3336):   at System.Type.GetType (System.String typeName, System.Boolean throwOnError) [0x0000e] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
10-14 16:47:00.571 I/MonoDroid( 3336):   at Java.Interop.TypeManager.n_Activate (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr typename_ptr, System.IntPtr signature_ptr, System.IntPtr jobject, System.IntPtr parameters_ptr) [0x00075] in <a48f8ed02442437495363c761e1d68a6>:0 
10-14 16:47:00.571 I/MonoDroid( 3336):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:b47f8a67-2a27-4b05-93ae-4b3fc59378b1 (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

> Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show
>   because all threads were executing external code (typically system or
>   framework code).
>
> The selected debug engine does not support any code executing on the
>   current thread (e.g. only native runtime code is executing).

I'm totally new to xamarin, so i suppose it is some basic, stupid mistake i made and did not configure IDE correctly.

Comment: Which Linking mode are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've spent whole freaking night on this thing, and literally nothing i found in the web worked. So i reinstalled whole vs 2017 and android SDK from the scratch. Now it works. Hardcore solution, but i could not find a root of the problem.